# Getting 500 internal server when using 'post' in ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I am working with JSP and ajax using jquery in my sample project. I am sending json data from  client to  server and in response I am getting another json from server. Everything works fine if I use 'get' method. If I use 'post' then I am getting 500 Internal server error.
My sample client side code is

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : "server.jsp",
    type : "POST",
    data:{req_data:JSON.stringify({"user_name":UserName,"url":URL})},
    async : false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error : function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
```

And my sample jsp server side code is

```
<%@ page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONValue"%>

request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter outt = response.getWriter();

JSONObject reqjsonObj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(request.getParameter("req_data"));
String uname=reqjsonObj.get("user_name").toString();
String url=reqjsonObj.get("url").toString();
JSONObject resjsonObj = new JSONObject();
resjsonObj.put("name",uname);
resjsonObj.put("url",url);
out.print(resjsonObj);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Everything works fine if I use 'GET' instead of 'POST' in ajax request. What is the possible mistake that I am making here?

Comment: Continuously debugging it :( ... One thing I hv observed. When sending thru 'get', in server request.getParameter("req_data") is having data but when sending thru 'post' it is null. Why? Any idea?

Comment: try removing `contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the URL:

```
 url : "server.jsp",
```

Maybe for some reason GET is able to find the jsp. For testing purposes try to declare all the url, something like:

```
 url : "http://localhost:8080/server.jsp"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sending json in the body of the request. You can't use `getParameter()` on the request to get the json.

Instead you can use `getReader()` or `getInputStream()` to retrieve the body of the request and then parse it for json.

Another approach is to use parameter that you serialize with the embedded json. In this case you can use `getParameter()`. How to serialize the data see [$.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).